# how to access https://localhost when using the "heroku local" command?

Tags: heroku, https

How do I test ssl/https of site using the "heroku local" command?

(this is regarding a ruby on rails site/repository)

Comment: You don't. `heroku local` doesn't serve over HTTPS. Why do you want this?

Comment: to reduce dev/prod parity

Comment: I imagine you mean to _increase_ parity (or decrease disparity). In any case, just develop using HTTP. Jumping through hoops to get local HTTPS is a lot of headache for virtually zero benefit. _Maybe_ use it on your test environments (but only if you can identify a concrete benefit beyond "reducing disparity"). HTTPS isn't "part of" your application. It's part of how it's hosted.

Comment: 8 rasons why you'd want ssl in development env: 
https://rossta.net/blog/local-ssl-for-rails-5.html

Comment: I'm still not convinced, but whatever floats your boat. `heroku local` doesn't support this. Feel free to set up a proxy with SSL or something.

Comment: I needed this because to process OAuth callbacks you need https. So it is a legit question

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your puma.rb

```
if Rails.env.development?

  localhost_key = "#{Dir.pwd}/#{File.join('config', 'certs', 'localhost.key')}"
  localhost_cert = "#{Dir.pwd}/#{File.join('config', 'certs', 'localhost.crt')}"

  unless File.exist?(localhost_key)
    def generate_root_cert(root_key)
      root_ca = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new
      root_ca.version = 2 # cf. RFC 5280 - to make it a "v3" certificate
      root_ca.serial = 0x0
      root_ca.subject = OpenSSL::X509::Name.parse "/C=BE/O=A1/OU=A/CN=localhost"
      root_ca.issuer = root_ca.subject # root CA's are "self-signed"
      root_ca.public_key = root_key.public_key
      root_ca.not_before = Time.now
      root_ca.not_after = root_ca.not_before + 2 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 # 2 years validity
      root_ca.sign(root_key, OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new)
      root_ca
    end

    root_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(2048)
    file = File.new( localhost_key, "wb")
    file.write(root_key)
    file.close

    root_cert = generate_root_cert(root_key)
    file = File.new( localhost_cert, "wb")
    file.write(root_cert)
    file.close
  end

  ssl_bind '0.0.0.0', '8443', {
    key: localhost_key,
    cert: localhost_cert
  }
end
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/tadast/9932075)